# Read data from firebase c#

Tags: c#, android, firebase

I cant find a way to read data from firebase databse in c# android application.
I want to read value from child data/test. Question appers to be very simple, couldnt find a aimple way which i would understand online

DATABASE picture:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lYlf.png)
Problem with reading screens
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmOLE.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdXus.png)

Working connection:

```
        var options = new Firebase.FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .SetApplicationId("1:191485419818:android:c3bef44f30f167e537be53")
            .SetApiKey("AIzaSyBwLcDZ3wGyzkwP6SobH8KDDsl5Vq227Vg")
            .Build();

        if (fireApp == null)
            fireApp = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this, options);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(fireApp);

        string FirebaseURL = "https://plsbrothers-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/";
        FirebaseClient rootNode = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseURL);

        dataNode = rootNode.Child("data");
        userNode = rootNode.Child("users");
```

//Trying to access the saved data and display it. Dont know it it is an issue with converting data to string and displaying it or i dont even access it properly (it shows Firebase.Database.Query.childQuery and not the data i want to display)

```
string testDisplay = dataNode.Child("test").ToString();
      
          TextView currentCharacterName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.test);
          currentCharacterName.Text = testDisplay;
```

XML CODE:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:text="save"
         android:textSize="25dp"
         android:textColor="#000"
         android:id="@+id/Btn"
         android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
/>

<TextView
    android:text="starting value"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/test" />
```

Comment: Did you check dataNode and userNode? are they null?

Comment: user node is empty, dataNode have email and name values inside. What im trying to do is to get and display the data from dataNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection:

```
FirebaseClient firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("Your Firebase URL");
```

Data Class, in these example it will be GalleryModel

```
public class GalleryModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

}
```

Generete new file(optionally) for Tasks. In these case file name is GalleryRepo

```
 public async Task<List<GalleryModel>>GetAll()
    {
        return (await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(GalleryModel)).OnceAsync<GalleryModel>()).Select(item => new GalleryModel
        {
            
            Name = item.Object.Name,
            Id = item.Key

        }).ToList();
    }
```

Create new xml file.

```
<StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="galleryListView" ItemsSource="{Binding gallerylist}" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">

                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">

                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Id}" FontSize="Medium"/>                 
                               
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Than in xml cs file

```
GalleryRepo galrepo = new GalleryRepo();

protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {

        var gallerylist = await GetAll();
        datesListView.ItemsSource = gallerylist;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//string testDisplay = dataNode.Child("test").ToString();
DatabaseReference testNode = dataNode.child("test");
string email = testNode.Object.Email.ToString()
string name = testNode.Object.Name.ToString()

TextView currentCharacterName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.test);
currentCharacterName.Text = email;
currentCharacterName.Invalidate();
```

//Please add the Invalidate() method.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work, setText method does not exist, when useing SetText method instead it ask to convert string with data to int which is not what i meant to. Thanks for trying to help tho, im really stuck at this one

Comment: Would you please post the XML of the TextView

Comment: Added xml file.

Comment: Please try with Invalidate() method at the end.

Comment: tried, does not work unfortunately, i added screens before and after clicking the button

Comment: It is displaying the node itself. You need to get the value in the node. I updated the code see if this works.